# Why isn't this for loop returning any non-false members?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, for-loop

This for loop isn't returning any `true` members.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    clientList[indexPath.row].s += 1

    if clientList[indexPath.row].s % 2 == 0 {
        clientList[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
    } else if clientList[indexPath.row].s % 2 != 0{
        clientList[indexPath.row].isSelected = false
    }
}
```

Here is the for-loop:

```swift
@IBAction func toClientsButton(_ sender: Any) {
    for y in 0...clientList.count - 1 {
        if clientList[y].isSelected == true {
            clientsSelected.append(clientList[y])
        }
    }
}
```

When the next screen loads, no values are in the `clientsSelected` array.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I wondered, what you trying here? if condition is  false thats why it not returning selected value., may be you are not checking that

Comment: In didSelectRowAt() what is the value of clientIndex in relation to indexPath.row? I'm curious if the if and else if cancel each other out.

Comment: Unrelated, but important: Don't use `0 ... x - 1`, use `0..<x`. Don't use `0..<array.count`, use `array.indices`. Don't use `for i in array.indices` unless you only need the index (which is rare), instead use `for client in clientList`. Don't compare a bool to `true` (`if b == true { ... }`, just do `if b { ... }`, unless it's optional (where `== true` becomes necessary. Also, your entire if statement can be replaced with a simple call to `filter`: `selectedClients += clientList.filter { $0.isSelected }`.

Comment: Also, as of Swift 5, there is `Int.isMultiple(of:)`, which makes the `i % 2 == 0` pattern obsolete. You should instead just write `if clientList[indexPath.row].s.isMultiple(of: 2) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: I guess `Client` is **struct** and you store them in different arrays. Structs are getting duplicated when passing around normally.

Comment: Whoops, just switched clientIndex to indexPath.row but came up with same result.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering out only selected clients:

```
let clientListSelected = clientList.filter { $0.isSelected }
```

Simpler logic for your *unknown purpose* logic

```
let client = clientList[indexPath.row]
client.isSelected = client.s.isMultiple(of: 2)
```

Comment: You can omit the `( )` in a trailing closure: `.filter { $0.isSelected }`

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured it out. I was trying to append everything the `array` with the `@IBAction` and segue to the next view controller at the same time, which loaded data from the `array`. Thanks for the answers, I changed up my code a bit as well.